# Update programmatically date modified on Woocommerce Orders

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime, woocommerce, orders

I'm getting a list of pending orders, grabbing some data and figuring if the post was last edited within 2 weeks.  If not I'm doing some stuff and then trying to set the modified date to today, the update_post_meta isn't working, it does nothing.  All of my declared vars at the top work and I am getting inside the if statement.

```
    $customer_orders = wc_get_orders(array(
        'limit'    => -1,
        'status'   => array('wc-pending')
    ) );

    foreach($customer_orders as $order) {

        $orderData = $order->get_data();
        $orderId = $orderData['id'];
        $orderDate = $orderData['date_modified']->date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $orderDatePlus2Weeks = new DateTime($orderDate);
        $orderDatePlus2Weeks->add(new DateInterval('P14D'));
        $orderDatePlus2Weeks = $orderDatePlus2Weeks->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        if($orderDatePlus2Weeks <= $today){
            echo 'THIS ORDER NEEDS UPDATED';
            // Do Some Stuff
            update_post_meta($orderId, 'date_modified', $today);
        }else{
            echo 'THIS ORDER DOES NOT NEED UPDATED';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Woocommerce 3 and [CRUD objects](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/CRUD-Objects-in-3.0), you can use `WC_Order` getters and setters methods. Try this:

```
$customer_orders = wc_get_orders(array(
    'limit'    => -1,
    'status'   => array('wc-pending')
) );

foreach($customer_orders as $order) {
    $order_id = $order->get_id();

    $date_modified = $order->get_date_modified();
    $time_zone = $date_modified->getTimezone();

    $date_modified_p14d = new DateTime($date_modified);
    $date_modified_p14d->add(new DateInterval('P14D'));

    $now = new DateTime();
    $now->setTimezone($time_zone);

    if( $date_modified_p14d->getTimestamp() <= $now->getTimestamp() ){
        echo 'THIS ORDER NEEDS UPDATED';
        // Do Some Stuff
        $order->set_date_modified($now->getTimestamp());
        $order->save();
    }else{
        echo 'THIS ORDER DOES NOT NEED UPDATED';
    }
}
```

Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but more importantly for the link about CRUD objects, that was a huge missing piece of my dev I didn't really know about!